# User Defaults with Group return wrong value after log out

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Inside my project I have a Main App and a Share Extension. For that I have two functions that both behave wrong. When first starting the app (after a complete deletion) everything works fine. As does the Share Extension. However if I log out of the app and the log back in, it is not able to retrieve `dataSourceArray` (always prints: "error getting datasourcearray" and calling `defaults.isLoggedIn()` always returns `true` even if I log out again.

**1. Function to check wether the user is logged in or not**

These are the two function inside `extension UserDefault`:

```
func setIsLoggedIn(value: Bool) {
    set(value, forKey: "isLoggedIn")
    synchronize()
}

func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    return bool(forKey: "isLoggedIn")
}
```

**2. function to set/get the dataSourceArray**

```
func setDataSourceArray(data: [Wishlist]?){
    set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(data), forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey)
    synchronize()
}


func getDataSourceArray() -> [Wishlist]? {
    if let data = self.value(forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey) as? Data {
        do {
            _ = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array < Wishlist > .self, from: data) as [Wishlist]
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let dataSourceArray =
            try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array < Wishlist > .self, from: data) as[Wishlist] {
                return dataSourceArray
            } 
    }
    return nil
}
```

This is what I call to **get** (always fires the `print` after I log out and back in again):

```
if defaults.isLoggedIn(){
      if let data = defaults.getDataSourceArray(){
              defaults.synchronize()
              self.dataSourceArray = data
       } else {
              print("Error getting dataSourceArray")
       }
}
```

This is what I do to log out the user:

```
if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.loginKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.dataSourceKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.dropOptionsKey)
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserDefaults.Keys.uid)
    defaults.synchronize()
} else {
    print("error Main")
}
```

At last here is how I **set**, when the user logs in:

```
DataHandler.getWishlists { (success, dataArray, dropOptionsArray)  in
        if success && dataArray != nil {
            self.dataSourceArray = dataArray as! [Wishlist]
            self.dropOptions = dropOptionsArray as! [DropDownOption]
            DataHandler.getWishes(dataSourceArray: self.dataSourceArray) { (success, dataSourceArrayWithWishes) in
                if success {
                    self.dataSourceArray = dataSourceArrayWithWishes

                    // save data to userDefaults
                    if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
                        defaults.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
                        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                        defaults.setUid(uid: uid)
                        defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: dataSourceArrayWithWishes)
                        defaults.setDropOptions(dropOptions: self.dropOptions)
                        defaults.synchronize()
                    } else {
                        print("error setting userdefaults")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems like all the `UserDefaults` get deleted once I rebuild the app with xcode or once I hard-restart it on the phone.
I hope all the `code` makes sense and is not confusing. I am stuck here and have no idea what going on so if anyone can help me I am very grateful!

**Update:** Here is my `MainNavigationController` to navigate to `Main` if the user logs in. It prints `true` but when I call the same `isLoggedIn` inside the `MainViewController` it prints `false`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
        print(defaults.isLoggedIn())
        if defaults.isLoggedIn() {
            let homeController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
            viewControllers = [homeController]
        } else {
            print("uuuum")
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I updated the question, I also tried it with `removeObject` when resetting the `Defaults` but it is still not working. Same behavior

Comment: Btw if anyone is too confused and whats to have a look at the whole project just let me know. I am clueless

Comment: I do not see any code in logout where you set `setIsLoggedIn` to false or delete it? That could be a reason you get `true` even after logout.

Comment: @SwapnilLuktuke youre right, that was acutally one issue. Well the issue was that I never actually signed out the user from `FIrebase`. I think there are some more issues, ill check that later

Answer (score 1):

**Under the logout function, you should add these code to clear the persistence of user default correctly:-**

```
let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
 UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
 UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Comment: should I actually use `standard`? I am using `suiteName:` everywhere else

Comment: Yes, you can go with the standard, then check what's the response.

Comment: doesnt do anything.

Comment: In the last function "DataHandler.getWishlists" you have set "defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: dataSourceArrayWithWishes)" add breakpoint after this line and print on console and check what data is to be set there?

Comment: it prints `false` for is logged in. I udpated my question. It makes no sense..

Comment: Hey Chris, you do the first logout, then login then prints "defaults.getDataSourceArray()" value . If it doesn't contain value then please confirm what parameter you have send in the header of API calls.  Because a few months ago I have to face the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218297/discussion-between-chris-and-ashutosh-kumar-mishra).

Comment: After logout, then login then prints the API Call value where dataSource value is to set i.e under the "DataHandler.getWishlists { (success, dataArray, dropOptionsArray)  in"
Could you check what value saved inside this line "defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: dataSourceArrayWithWishes)"